Rider auto collapse doc comments by default when open file
I'm working on a project in Rider and whenever I open any file, it contains document comments. By default, these comments are expanded, but I prefer to have them collapsed automatically when I open a file. I know how to manually collapse them, but I'm looking for a way to make this the default behavior.
Does anyone know how to set document comments to be collapsed by default in Rider/VS? Any tips or plugins that might help?

Go to Settings => Editor => General => Code Folding. In Fold by default section, check Documentation comments.

